# Nginx Rewrite URL to contain the wildcard subdomain and change domain suffix at the same time

Tags: url, redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

Need some help... I need to rewrite urls for local images in nginx. Here are some rules.

If the image isn't on the file system then rewrite the url.
The url can be a a wildcard subdomain
The domain suffix needs to be changed to .com

**So as an example**

```
a.example.dev -> a.example.com

b.example.dev -> b.example.com

*.example.dev -> *.example.com
```

At the end I need to append the image url, here is a full example

**Original**

```
http://www.engineering.example.dev/files/2015/05/filename.gif
```

**Final**

```
http://www.engineering.example.com/files/2015/05/filename.gif
```

**Original**

```
http://www.example.dev/files/2015/05/filename.gif
```

**Final**

```
http://www.example.com/files/2015/05/filename.gif
```

Any help would be greatly apprechiated.

Answer (score 1):

The [regular expression server name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) can collect the wildcard subdomain in a named capture. You can then use `try_files` to conditionally redirect to the `.com` domain.

For example:

```
server {
    server_name  "~^(?<name>.+)\.dev$";

    root /path/to/root;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @redirect;
    }
    location @redirect {
        return 301 $scheme://$name.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```